# Create a jpeg file in c:\imagesFolder based on the Image stored in the database in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have pictures of each employee stored in SQL database with Image database.

```
Select pic from empimages where emp_ID=10
```

give the picture of that employee in binary format.

How do I create a physical jpeg in C:\images folder based on the above query in vb.net.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a good tutorial relating to this: [Creating Binary Files using Visual Basi](http://www.airfieldmodels.com/other/software/vbdb/how_to_read_and_write_binary_files.htm)c

You should be able to just take the data from the blob and write it to a file this way. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

In what format do you have the file? As a byte array? In that case, simply write

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes( _
    "C:\images\" & imagename & ".jpg", ImageData, False)
```